For the Monetoo Tic-Tac-Toe, is there any hint on where to place the red stone? Or is it just trying all the places?
Monetoo, Three, Four... as the Wiki calls it, has a puzzle to involve yourself with some Monetoo playing Tic-Tac-Toe by placing a stone down to help one side win.
Is there any in-game hint on where to place the stone? Or are you just supposed to either try all the available spaces or look up how to solve the game?

I.... seriously suppose you didn't visit the actual puzzle location before asking this question, did you?
There are two elements here: telling you that the game is tic-tac-toe, and getting you to make a win move.
As for telling you that the game is indeed Tic-Tac-Toe, Paimon herself will comment as soon as you get near to the puzzle.

Then the two Monetoo will play for a while before stopping again, at which point Paimon refers to the missing red stone for the next move.

Finally, if you look at the board...

you will probably recognize that by playing an "X" in the top left corner you achieve a win condition as the other player can't block both your attacks.

No, no, I visited the location, I just couldn't / didn't spend the time to parse the board right.
